# Set color for a node of particular commit in Gitgraph

Tags: reactjs, gitgraph.js

I import Git tree as JSON in **Gitgraph** for React. I want to color a node for commit with particular hash in red, like on the pic.

Is there a native way in Gitgraph.js to achieve this?

[image]

```
{this.props.git && this.props.git.log &&
 <Gitgraph>
     {gitgraph => {
         gitgraph.import(this.props.git.log)
     }}
 </Gitgraph>
}
```

Comment: I assume you are talking about  https://gitgraphjs.com ?

Comment: @FelixKling yes

Comment: https://gitgraphjs.com/stories/?path=/story/gitgraph-react-1-basic-usage--branch-colors

Comment: @jaybhatt That's about how to color a whole branch, not one commit. Or I miss something there?

Comment: I think there are more examples of how you can also pass custom styles and classes, that ought to cover it. If you can spend some time.